# Plugin Development - Template Resources?

Tags: plugin-development, plugins

I'm in the middle of creating a plugin that needs a template to display information stored in some records when the user clicks this in the CMS sidebar.

I've managed to get the template to appear (Yay!) And I've been looking at other plugins with regards to styling / structure of these pages.

A lot of them are extending and using classes that appear within Craft.

Is there a reference to this anywhere? Such as a class / styleguide or any where I can find out a bit easier what blocks etc are used?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No such reference currently exists. Your best bet is to backwards-engineer what you see in the control panel.

Since the makers of Craft do such a great job of "eating their own dog food", they've made sure that most of their CSS classes are fairly generic and reusable. So if you see an element that you want to imitate (ie: a button), just inspect the element, and copy its classes.

Comment: That's a shame :( But yeah I've just been looking through other peoples plugins and also the control panel for the classes.

Oh well! I'll crack on